# How to stop chained requests on error using Restangular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I'm using Restangular to get data by chained promises. Here's a simplified example of what I'm doing:

```
Restangular.one("employer").get().then(function(employer) {
    return employer;
}, function(response) {
    //response.status === '401'
    $location(login);
}).then(function(company) {
    Restangular.one("reviews?company_name='" + company).get()
    .then(function(reviews) {
        $scope.reviews = reviews.originalElement;
    });
});
```

First I need to get the user's employer and then the reviews attached to this employer. I think it works fine until I get a 401 response back from the server.

When it happens, I send the user to the login screen. This also works fine, but the problem is that the whole chain gets executed – which will return in one more 401.

Ultimately I'd like the chain to stop when the error occurs. I could probably do it by throwing an error, but is that really a good solution? Am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your error handler, you need to `return false;` to stop the promise chain:

```
Restangular.one("employer").get().then(function(employer) {
    return employer;
}, function(response) {
    //response.status === '401'
    $location(login);
    return false
}).then(function(company) {
    Restangular.one("reviews?company_name='" + company).get()
    .then(function(reviews) {
        $scope.reviews = reviews.originalElement;
    });
});
```